# Date of Birth selector problem in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm using a javascript date selector within a HTML form, and it's displaying as it should in the browsers I've tested in (Firefox 3, Opera 9, Chrome, IE7) but it displays really large in IE6.

Here's the page I'm talking about - http://marketplace.prettypollution.com/kids-club

Any ideas?

Comment: I would love to help, but I do not have access to IE6 on any system at my disposal (all of them are either Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 2008.) Could you post a screenshot of how it looks in IE6, and possibly your CSS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table that the date selector is in has `width:100%` getting applied to it by the

```
table {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

selector in your `screen.css` file.

If you make the width of the table for the date picker table (the one with `class="date"`) some fixed value, or `auto`, it will look fine in IE6.

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="form_box">
<select style="height:20px; width:50px; border:1px solid #75B8C9; background:#D3C9B4; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000;">
<option>DD</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select style="height:20px; width:50px; border:1px solid #75B8C9; background:#D3C9B4; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000;">
<option>MM</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select style="height:20px; width:80px; border:1px solid #75B8C9; background:#D3C9B4; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000;">
<option>YYYY</option>
</select>
</div>
```